# Add Key to All Array of Object Without map or looping

Tags: javascript

I am having an **Array of Object** and want to add new key over all the object in the Array

```
let data = [{name:"xyz"},{name:"abc"}]
let age = 5
```

I **don't want to loop over** the Array and add the key because **array length is more then 200**

Expected Result

```
let data = [{name:"xyz",age:5},{name:"abc",age:5}]
```

Comment: It's impossible. Any reasonable sort of code *will* involve a loop somewhere, even if abstracted behind a function. Technically, you could do it without a loop by hard-coding each index, but please don't do that

Comment: 200 isn't all that many. I think you are optimising prematurely

Comment: On Firefox and an AMD FX-8350, adding `age` to one million objects using `forEach` took 13 milliseconds. Edit: Chrome took 152.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Object.prototype.age = 5;
```

Voilà, every object now has that age.

No, seriously. If you want to add a property to 200 objects, you have to add it to 200 objects.

Sample working snippet

```js
let data = [{name:"xyz"},{name:"abc"}]

Object.prototype.age = 5

data.forEach(o => console.log(o.name, o.age))


// Every Object will have the age property because the age
// has been added to the prototype of Object see below



const someRandomArrayOfObj = [{}, {}]

someRandomArrayOfObj.forEach(o => console.log(o.age))


const a = {}

console.log(a.age)
```